# How to make a conditional statement with two parameter do not consists of repetitive statements without using external function in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Let there be two boolean variables `a` and `b`, and each combination of the truth values of both causes a particular different procedure. Check this code:

```
if(a)
{
    // Block A
    if(b)
    {
        // statement 1
    } 
    else 
    {
        // statement 2
    }
}
else {
    // Block B
    if(b)
    {
        // statement 3
    }
    else
    {
        // statement 4
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it to be not repetitive without making a separate function? (What I mean by repetitive is block A and block B have the same conditional but different statement)

Comment: `if(a || b){ statement1 }else{ statement2 }` ?

Comment: If both blocks do the same thing, Why write an else block. Simply delete the else block? Or simply combine the if A and if B condition into one If

Comment: Please update your question to clarify if this is more than the comments indicate and just a simple change to your code.

Comment: @Rafalon No, if `a` is true, sometimes statement 2 still needs to be executed.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yeah right, it really is `if(b){ 1 }else{ 2 }` we apparently don't care about `a`

Comment: My bad, I mean each conditional statement does different procedures. Let me update the question

Comment: @Rafalon OP has updated the question. `if(b)` now seems to be right.

Comment: If blocks A and B are the same (as in your example), then the whole `if(a){}else{}` is useless

Comment: I have updated my question. Is that the most succinct way to do it since it seems repetitive to me?

Comment: If the 4 blocks are different, then I don't really see what more succinct way could be than what you wrote. Did you expect a solution with less than 4 blocks?

Comment: Does it work and is it readable enough to your team?

Comment: Yeah, it works and does readable, I am just curious if it can be done in a more succinct way (less than 4 blocks). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) work for you?

```
(a, b) switch {
    (true, true) => ...,
    (true, false) => ...`,
    (false, true) => ...,
    (false, false) => ...,
};
```

Comment: The question has been edited since.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid nesting `if`s like so

```
if(a && b)
{
    // statement 1
}
else if(a && !b)
{
    // statement 2
}
else if(!a && b)
{
    // statement 3
}
else
{
    // statement 4
}
```

I'm not sure you would consider it more succint, but I at least find it more readable.